# how to create a smooth tabBar like the video

Tags: android, native, tabbar

am working an android native app , and searching for a way to develop a Tab Bar like the one in this video :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unKs-b80aTU&feature=player_embedded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe take a look at this example, it could give you some ideas on creating a Scrollable TabHost:

http://code.google.com/p/mobyfactory-uiwidgets-android/